# copy database from assets to databases folder of a separate application

Tags: android, apk

As I have seen other places I have gotten the bottom following two things to work. The application has a button that says copy and onClick it will move the .db file from the assets directory of the running apk to the databases directory of the file.

I would like to know though if its possible to take the DB file and copy it over to the databases directory of an application but not the application currently running?

Or to be more clear my question is can someone give me an example or show me how to edit my code below to place the copied .db in a different app directory than the one that is currently running at the time the db copy and move is being done?

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

//The Android's default system path of your application database.
private static String DB_PATH ="/data/data/com.rtt.bltc/databases/";
private static String DB_NAME = "ldeb.db";

private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
private final Context myContext;

/**
 * Constructor
 * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
 * @param context
 */
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {

    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.myContext = context;
    DB_PATH="/data/data/"+context.getPackageName()+"/"+"databases/";
    //DB_PATH="/data/data/com.rtt.bltc"+"/"+"databases/";
}
```

/**
     * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
     * */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

```
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if(dbExist){
        //do nothing - database already exist
    }else{

        //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
           //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
        this.getReadableDatabase();

        try {

            copyDataBase();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            throw new Error("Error copying database");

        }
    }

}

/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */
private boolean checkDataBase(){

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try{
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }catch(SQLiteException e){

        //database does't exist yet.

    }

    if(checkDB != null){

        checkDB.close();

    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
 * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
 * This is done by transfering bytestream.
 * */
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

    //Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {

        if(myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();

        super.close();

}



@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
```

//return cursor
    public Cursor query(String table,String[] columns, String selection,String[] selectionArgs,String groupBy,String having,String orderBy){
        return myDataBase.query("profiles", null, null, null, null, null, null);

```
}
```

}

I have included a copy of the CopyDb and the Helper class above and below.

```
public class CopyDbActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
Cursor c=null;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.button01)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


             DatabaseHelper myDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(CopyDbActivity.this);
             try {

                myDbHelper.createDataBase();

        } catch (IOException ioe) {

            throw new Error("Unable to create database");

        }

        try {

            myDbHelper.openDataBase();

        }catch(SQLException sqle){

            throw sqle;

        }
        Toast.makeText(CopyDbActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



        c=myDbHelper.query("profiles", null, null, null, null,null, null);
        if(c.moveToFirst())
        {
            do {

                Toast.makeText(CopyDbActivity.this,
                        "_id" + c.getString(0) + "\n" +
                        "UUID" + c.getString(1) + "\n" +
                        "NAME" + c.getString(2) + "\n" +
                         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         } while (c.moveToNext());
                 }
             }
    });        
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know though if its possible to take the DB file and copy it over to the databases directory of an application but not the application currently running?

No. Your app does not have *read* access to another app's portion of internal storage, let alone write access.

Comment: Right, but is it possible to do? Can I give access in the code some how or impersonate a user, or make the move withhold root privledges somehow in the code?

Comment: @Pr3tty8oyfl0yd: "but is it possible to do?" -- no. "Can I give access in the code some how" -- if you are writing both apps, you can use `FileProvider` to "serve" the database to the other app. You give it a `Uri` from `FileProvider.getUriForFile()`, then it can open an `InputStream` on that database and copy it over. In other words, you can *pull*, but not *push*.

Comment: Do you actually need to copy the db file around between apps, though, @Pr3tty8oyfl0yd? If you control both apps, you can also look into implementing [Content Providers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) to share data between them.